# how to restrict send email in followers in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I want to restrict sending email when we perform send message in logger
[image]

[image: for this i have added configuration in attached photos]

for this i have added configuration in attached photos
for e.g: i want to restrict all users whos email dont have domain example.com

i have 3 followers in record 2 have @example.com domain in their email and last follower doesn't have @example.com in domain
so when any email found i want to open wizard and in that wizard 
i want to ask users whether you want to send email or not
if yes then it will send to all 
and if no the close the wizard and remove users which email domain is not @example.com

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: till now i have tried to popup wizard in mail.mail create ,mail.mail @api.constraint
i am able to get outeside domain partners but i am not able to open wizard from chatter

Answer (score 0):

**I Think you can check with manually split email Address.**

If you send mail that time you customisation methods and check email address (
alias_domain) which is split value is same as your requirement(@example.com) . if This email address is belong @example.com that time append ID and send Mail otherwise not.

I think Odoo not Provided particular Domain or alias_domain in mail Id.